# How do I create a custom view filter for an existing field?

Tags: views, 8

I ran into a problem with creating a custom view filter for an existing field for Drupal 8. I mean a filter not for fields like "nid", "title" and so on, but for fields, which were named CCK-fields first.

Could you share with me an understandable example of code, how to create this plugin?

I tried to comprehend some examples in contrib modules, like the geolocation module, but that code was very sophisticated. Also, I haven't found adequate manuals anywhere.

Comment: Are you referring to field plugin? If yes, check https://www.webomelette.com/creating-custom-views-field-drupal-8

Comment: Unfortunately, that example is not for CCK-fields.
What do I want? For example, after installing Drupal there is a node type "article", which contains a field "tags". Foer example, I have got a great idea and I want to create awesome views filter by this field.

Comment: This article demonstrates how to create a filter on existing field. https://www.lilengine.co/articles/custom-views-filter-existing-daterange-field

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to code your Views filter, in your Articles View, you have a Filter criteria section where you may add views filters based on many different entities, including fields (what you call CCK fields)￼.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I mean how to create my new filter plugin programmatically, not via admin-interface. I haven't found any understandable code for it.

Comment: OK, my mistake then, my answer is useless to you.